# Permission denied error when running crontab

Tags: linux, cron

I have created an r-script in the folder "csv_file"

```
marc@Marc-Linux:~/csv_file$ ls
8388.26580527145.csv  csv_file.Rproj  excel  source  write_csv2.R
```

Now I would like to create a crontab that executes this file every five minutes till 10am. Therefore I wrote the following

```
  #open crontab
  crontab -e
  #add to file
  */5 10 * * * ~/csv_file/write_csv2.R
```

This however does not seem to work. That makes sense cause when I try to run

```
  marc@Marc-Linux:~$ ~/csv_file/write_csv2.R
```

I get the following error:

```
  -bash: /home/marc/csv_file/write_csv2.R: Permission denied
```

Any thoughts what goes wrong here?

Comment: `chmod +x /home/marc/csv_file/write_csv2.R`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it executable first, using

```
chmod +x  ~/csv_file/write_csv2/filename.r
```

and the execute it using ./filename.r

Comment: on cron he needs path off file, best if use full path

Comment: Indeed, `~` is a Bashism, and will not work in `cron`, which requires pure `sh` syntax.  But `cron` runs from your home directory, so you can simply say `./csv_file/write_csv2.R` in the  `crontab` file.